# How do I select a default in the Position Select field?

Tags: field, position

Just getting around to adding advanced layout features to our site, when I say advanced I just mean floated images left & right. The problem I seem to have though is that `left` is always the default position.

There is a way around it if I disable left & right and use drop-left & drop-right but I think it would be more usable if we were able to set a default.

Comment: I don't think there's currently any way to do this. I agree though: it would be a great feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there's no settings option to define a default, there's two things you can do:

1. Copy / fork the field type and add the option or simply hack it to your needs.
2. Contact P&T and make a feature request for setting field type defaults for Position select (and others).